# Installing cordova with older android SDK version

Tags: android, cordova, sdk

I have an android project build up on cordova 3.6.3. I'm trying to upgrade it to 5.2.2 from scratch. However, I have a problem with the android SDK.

The process I'm using is:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add android --save
cordova build android
```

And what I receive is:

Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:

```
Path: platforms/android
Package: com.example.hello
Name: HelloWorld
Activity: MainActivity
Android target: android-23
```

So the Android target is the SDK23. In my project I'm using some libraries such as org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient which have been deprecated since SDK 21. As a consequence I'm trying to create the cordova on SDK 20 and not on 23.

Is there any way to do that from the cordova cli or in another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your target API version to be different then change it in **ANdroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

Edit these lines. Here `android:targetSdkVersion` is your Android version that you are targeting.

Comment: Thanks Hassan. I have tried it but I still get that it cannot find  org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient;

Comment: org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient; its didn't support this android      version ? Right

Comment: Yes...the org.apache.cordoa.CordovaWebViewClient is supposed to be from sdk 20 and previously...I'm not sure if replacing classes with equivalent one and remodifying code would change anything

Comment: You can find some relevant plugin which have similar  functioning.